# onclick get this textContent of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, nodes

```
<div class="myclass">
<ul>
<li><a> first node <i>textContent</i></a></li>
<li><a>textContent1</a></li>
<li><a>textContent2</a></li>
<li><a>textContent3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".myclass ul li").live("click", function() {
alert(this.textContent);
});
```

I wish to get the value of `<a>` element using onclick

and first `<li>` I wish to get the value of `<i>` element.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try `$(this).find("i").text();` to get the `<i>`'s text. Also, note that `live` has been deprecated in favor of `on`

Answer (score 2):

use `text()` :

```
$(document).on("click", ".myclass ul li", function() {
    var txt = $('i', this).length ? $('i', this).text() : $(this).text();
    alert( txt );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQadA/)

Also, `live()` has been deprecated and removed, and to get the text of the i element if such an element exists, you check if exists and the act appropriately

Comment: also i want cross browser solution.