# Can't figure out how to grab value of button click event and paste it into a text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been building this app that helps people play Yahtzee without dice. It's essentially a random number generator visually displayed in the DOM.

I'm trying to add in some extra functionality by letting players click on the generated numbers which are stored in the DOM in button elements. And by clicking on them it stores that number into the text input field below that.

I tried multiple different things to paste the value into the input field but nothing seems to work or throw any errors. Logging the value to the console on click works just fine.

TLDR explanation in video(sorry for shitty audio): https://www.loom.com/share/449c370364b448349e20a06085dae5d5

Github link: https://github.com/Roaldkamman/Portfolio_YahtzeeDice

most important code piece I'm trying to fix:

```
$(".dice-button").on("click", ".btn_1", function() { 
    $(".myInput").value = this.textContent + ", ";
});
```

How logging to the console works:

```
$(".dice-button").on("click", ".btn_2", function() { 
    console.log(this.textContent); 
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387430/onclick-get-this-textcontent-of-an-element

Comment: Try `$('.myInput).value(this.textContent)`; IIRC `$.value` is a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.value` is a property on a HTML input element, not on the jQuery object. So, you should either use jQuery's [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value, or retrieve the HTML element from the object:

```
$(".myInput").val(this.textContent + ", ");
```

...or:

```
$(".myInput")[0].value = this.textContent + ", ";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Terry. How would I do a += in this case? I need the field to retain its previous input. video explanation: https://www.loom.com/share/dc8b6738b7fa43b4ab7a6c26052a4be4

Comment: nevermind I figured it out :) $(".dice-button").on("click", ".btn_1", function() { 
    $(".myInput").val($(".myInput").val() + this.textContent + ", ");
});

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery use method `val()` in input element

```
$(".myInput").val(this.textContent + ", ")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help too! You suggested the same as Terry. Just figuring out how to do a += operation in this scenario.

Comment: You can do it next way: 
```$(".myInput").val($(".myInput").val() + this.textContent + ", ")```